# cordova.plugins is undefined in my android phonegap (ionic)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

In my phonegap application for android, in app.js, I am trying to execute

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
```

in app.js but I am getting cordova.plugins as undefined. Now in my index.html I have included cordova.js file. But which file I need to include to make plugins available to cordova global variable? I am not able to understand how to make cordova.plugins available. window.plugins is available but backgroundMode is undefined then. Please help me out here. It seems I am missing out some conceptual part.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I dont know how but I solved my issue by creating a new project again. There might be some mistake from my side while creating the previous app.